# Spring security management console

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to add the spring security management console which is shown in the spring security ui documentation.
It does not however tell you how to access it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good entry point is the user controller (`grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.UserController`).  If you are using the default URL mappings you will be able to access it at `http://localhost:8080/<appname>/user` in development mode.

Comment: It seems on the documentation there is a management console already in the spring UI plugin. Im just want to know if there is a URL for it or not. the URL http://localhost:8080/<appname>/user just renders index from my controller. is there another way. Its just those screens look nice to use as admin screens.